Getting Inconsistent padding in tailwind css (on react+vite)
I am getting this type of padding /border . Click the link below to view.
[Inconsistent padding in tailwind]
Want like this
(https://i.sstatic.net/2RsqliM6.png)
I was trying to get border with gradient from top to bottom of purple-900 to purple-600. But i don't know how to do that.
So I wrapped each card in in a div and provided padding of p-0.5 but It doesn't seem to be consistent padding from all sides.
Any solutions.
Here is the Code of card layout .


const PlanCard = ({ price, features, onHover, isHovered }) => {
  return (
    <div className="p-2px rounded-lg bg-gradient-to-b from-purple-900 to-purple-500">
    <div
      className={`w-full min-w-50 flex-col max-w-xs p-6 rounded-md shadow-lg transition-transform duration-300 ease-in-out ${
        isHovered ? 'bg-gradient-to-b from-purple-900 to-purple-600 text-white scale-110' : 'bg-white'
      } transition-colors duration-300`}
      onMouseEnter={onHover}
      onMouseLeave={onHover}
    >
      <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">{price}</h2>
      <ul className="text-left">
        {features.map((feature, index) => (
          <li key={index} className="mb-2">
            <h3 className="font-semibold">{feature.title}</h3>
            <ul className="list-disc list-inside">
              {feature.points.map((point, idx) => (
                <li key={idx}>{point}</li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button className="mt-4 w-full 
        bg-purple-500 text-white py-2 rounded hover:bg-purple-700 [enter image description here][1]active:bg-purple-900 active:scale-90">
        SELECT
      </button>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
};



export default PlanCard;



Want to get the consistent padding or border with gradient around the div.

There could be many reasons for this including the margins on your cards. Also, p-2px will have no effect, it should be written as p-[2px]
I would also recommend doing gradients via CSS or inline and not tailwind.

I  have already specified in my tailwind config '2px':'2px'
But even tough i use p-0.5 or p-1 or anything not getting the consistent padding.
Don't know why it's happening

If you want to use px in Tailwind, you should write it as p-[2px] or p-0.5 (which means 2px).
For more details, you can refer to the Tailwind documentation.
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/padding
